# Lab Jack with Bi-Dimensional Movement

Tags: mechanical-engineering, design, mechanisms

I just bought a lab jack like this one:

[image]

Its purpose is to change its height without loosing its rigidity by using the so called: scissors mechanism

[image]

I was wondering if there is a similar device like that one, but instead of changing its height, that could change its width too. Some sort of Lab Jack with bi-dimensional movement (X and Y instead of just Y)

Comment: What problem would it solve?  Your 6 axles linking scissors would have to expand (contract), identically.  The base and platform would have to expand.  Existing mechanism shifts top support to one half of platform.  Combo would have a quarter.

Comment: well, it would be better if they expand and contract separately. I want some sort of adjustable platform in both axis

Comment: I want my experiment to enter in a tight place. This place changes size with each different experiment so it would be great to have some sort of platform that I can adjust its size deliberately in both X and Y direction

Comment: Get scissor lift to fit smallest possible dimensions and capacity and use different size upper platform.

Comment: [Automotive Scissor Lift](https://www.pond5.com/3d-models/item/90656814-automotive-scissor-lift)  Use two Sissor Lifts to lift.  Probably another 2 on top and bottom to expand platform.

Comment: @DieDauphin for the horizontal movement are you looking for extension of the platform or just translation?

Comment: Sounds like you want to mount the lift onto a miniature milling slide

Comment: Extension of the platform, is for an injection molding machine, I need to adjust the height and width of the platform where I'm placing the mold. Each different mold requires a platform with different height and width, so it is an annoyance to find different scraps of metal that fit the needed size (what I'm doing now). It would be better to have a single device that could change its height and width

Comment: Perhaps build onto the top surface of the jack some telescoping rails that can extend its width, if you don't mind having a somewhat narrow base of support. Or use two jacks, with link connecting drive screws, and vary the distance between them (with telescoping base, like an adjustable shop dolly?)

Comment: All right, I'm going to try to do that, once I finished I will post my solution, thanks

Comment: You should add your comments to the question since they are relevant for any answer.